# Assigning a DataTable value to a Variable

Tags: c#, datatable, format

I just wrote a simple method to get some data from an SQL server and store it in a DataTable.

Specifically the value is an integer : 666

It is an int datatype on the database and I made a variable called Credits in C# which is also an integer.

The datatable shows the value 666 in the first row so it got added without any problems.

The problem happens when I try to assign `Credits = dt.Rows[0]` saying

> the inputstring was an incorrect format

Ive tried parsing it to an int and adding .ToString() but no matter what it gives the same error.

the latest line I tried was

```
Credits = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0].ToString());
```

But still no luck. I have looked everywhere online for a solution but I cannot find the problem.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing column name while selecting data from Data Table. You can either use column name or column index.

```
int Credits = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["columnname"].ToString());
```

Please make sure that value of that column value should not be null or empty.If thats the case you have to check that before assigning to int variable.

Or You can use, TryParse

```
int Credits = int.TryParse(dt.Rows[0]["columnname"].ToString());
```

Comment: Yes! That was it!
Dammit it's always some stupid thing I overlook that makes me look like an idiot.
Thank you very very much for your help, hopefully I'll be able to return the favor on here one day when I stop being bad at programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a entire row inside a variable

string Credits = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["columname"].ToString());

Comment: Thank you as well for taking the time to answer my question!